# Text messages didn't deliver but show as sent on Messages but not in Messages+

Tags: samsung, sms

I had two text messages not get delivered to someone even though they show as sent in the Samsung Messages app (on Galaxy S21).  I went to the Verizon Messages+ app and they don't show there at all.  What might have caused this / is there some way to prevent or investigate it?

Comment: @Robert normally both apps can see all messages by the other app, and same goes if I install Android Messages by Google. I think they write to local storage.

Comment: I think that Samsung used to have background services that "shared" data to similar products like Messages/Messages+ . This was before strict application sandboxing, isolating apps from doing this as a security measure. I think this is why users are questioned to make a "default" message app choice when it appears a second is trying to take over. It will use your choice to import the data to the permitted one. Google may be getting around this because its Google Framework interlinks all the Google-faced apps, or, most likely, it violates its own rules when expedient.

Comment: @wbogacz not sure what the OP did, but I use Truecaller on Samsung as the default SMS app, and Google Messages wouldn't show any messages if it's not set as the default SMS app. However, Samsung Messages could still see all messages without being set as the default SMS app, probably a privilege as a system app.

Comment: @AndrewT. One last guess as to how Google Message got into the mix. Maybe the OP enabled his laptop to act as a texting device, too, and never disabled that? I remember doing that for all of maybe a day, until I had to turn it off!

Comment: Ah yes @wbogacz I think I used the "Phone Link" app on Windows to send at least one and maybe both of those messages. Good call.